# Getting the another title on Facebook SignIn button?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

![on facebook sigin button im getting the login with Facebook title.Actual my button is Sign in with facebook]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried below -

```
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    [[FBSDKLoginManager new] logOut];
```

Also you post your code which help us to identify the issue.

Comment: [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
 [FBSession.activeSession close];

Comment: Thank you , If above code is solved your problem then please mark it correct and do upvote. So that others people can get help